# Nginx try_file for Subpath location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'm finding difficult to understand try_file for my case.

as a example

URl - https://devops.com/prod/devops-admin-angular this will be rewrite https://devops.com/devops-admin-angular.
after hitting this url https://devops.com/prod/devops-admin-angular, Angular page is calling to some static file or other js scripts. as a example https://devops.com/devops-admin-angular/script.js on browser level.

This is working fine and below is the code.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name    poc-devops.devops.com;
  access_log /tmp/devops-access.log;
  error_log /tmp/devops-error.log;

  location ~ /prod/devops-admin-angular(/|$)(.*) {
    rewrite ^/prod/devops-admin-angular(/|$)(.*) /devops-admin-angular/$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10008;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }
}
```

after hitting this url https://devops.com/prod/devops-admin-angular, Angular page is calling to some static file or other js scripts. as a example https://devops.com/devops-admin-angular/script.js on browser level.

I'm not able to understand how can i use try_file.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name    poc-devops.devops.com;
  access_log /tmp/devops-access.log;
  error_log /tmp/devops-error.log;

  location ~ /prod/devops-admin-angular(/|$)(.*) {
    try_files $uri/prod/ /prod/devops-admin-angular;
    rewrite ^/prod/devops-admin-angular(/|$)(.*) /devops-admin-angular/$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10008;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  }
}
```